# Is there a name for a graph (as in, graph theory) made from a system of equations?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology, systems-of-equations

Let's say I have a set of $n$ variables, $X = \{x_1,...,x_n\}$.  If it matters, all variables are real.  Further suppose I have $m$ subsets of these variables, $X_1,...,X_m$ and $m$ functions of the form $f_i(X_i) = 0$.  The notation there means that $f_i$ is a function of all of the variables in subset $X_i$.

In my particular application, some of these subsets have nonempty intersection, and the union of all subsets equals the entire set of variables.

I can construct a graph as follows:

Assign each variable $x_j$ to a vertex of the graph.  Assign an edge $e_{i,j}$ whenever $x_i$ and $x_j$ belong to the same function.  (I am open to the possibility of these two variables belonging to multiple functions, but haven't yet decided if that means there should be multiple edges between them.)

I've been using this graph to study dependence/independence of the variables in the set.  I've heard that there is something called a "matroid" that describes such dependencies, but I'm not sure if I actually have a matroid or not.

So:

1. Does this type of graph have a name?  (is it a matroid?  If not, does my setup of the system of equations have anything to do with matroids, and should I be considering them as such?)
2. Is my construction of the graph valid?  What should I do if there are multiple edges?

Comment: I'm not aware of a name for this particular graph.  However, you're dropping a lot of information about the functions: coefficients and exponents, for example.  Every graph determines a matroid, by the way, so I'm not sure that's the right avenue to pursue.  There's nothing invalid about your description of the graph, but I'm not sure how useful it is.

Comment: Can't any graph be constructed with this set up?

Comment: @AaronDall: it's the semantics that are important here.  The fact that edges represent functions.  However, this is an old question, and I've since come up with a much more useful graph.  I've stopped using the graph described above.

Comment: I'm curious to know what the graph is. For example, in your new set up, what is the graph associated to the kernel of the matrix $M = [[1,1,1,1],[1,2,3,4]]$? The matrix $M$ is a representation of the uniform matroid $U_{2,4}$, which is perhaps the most famous non-graphic matroid.

Comment: @AaronDall: the new graph is simpler than the above: nodes represent functions, edges represent common variables.  I suppose this would be a multigraph, since two functions may share multiple variables.  Using this graph we can do interesting things.  For instance, starting at one node and assuming all of its variables are known, we might walk to another node, considering all variables on all edges as unknowns.  I'm studying which walks leads to solvable systems of equations (a bit hard to explain in a comment :P )